# Calcite JDBC-Spark Integration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-calcite

I have a requirement to query the multiple data sources in single SQL query. I saw Calcite provides this with a JDBC adapter. While running this, I encountered the following challenges:

1. Execution was happening in memory which causes OOM on big data.
2. I saw there is an option for Spark. If this option is enabled, will the query be executed using Spark?
3. If the answer to the 2nd question is yes, when I am trying to execute the query using the Spark option, I am getting the following exception:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at CalciteProgram84650.bind(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalcitePrepare$CalciteSignature.enumerable(CalcitePrepare.java:355)
       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.enumerable(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:309)
       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteMetaImpl._createIterable(CalciteMetaImpl.java:506)
       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteMetaImpl.createIterable(CalciteMetaImpl.java:497)
       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaResultSet.execute(AvaticaResultSet.java:182)
       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteResultSet.execute(CalciteResultSet.java:64)
       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteResultSet.execute(CalciteResultSet.java:43)
       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection$1.execute(AvaticaConnection.java:667)
       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteMetaImpl.prepareAndExecute(CalciteMetaImpl.java:566)
       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareAndExecuteInternal(AvaticaConnection.java:675)
       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:156)
       ... 2 more
```

4. And please let me know how to overcome OOM when big data execution.

**Java class**

```
package com.sixdee.calcite;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.calcite.util.Sources;
public class MultiJDBCSchemaJoinTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            Properties info = new Properties();
            info.put("model", jsonPath("model"));
            info.put("spark", "true");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
            String sql = "SELECT SUB_DETAILS.MSISDN FROM DB1.SUB_DETAILS";
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    resultSet = null;
                }
            }
            if (statement != null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    statement = null;
                }
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    connection = null;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static String jsonPath(String model) {
        return resourcePath(model + ".json");
    }

    public static String resourcePath(String path) {
        return Sources.of(MultiJDBCSchemaJoinTest.class.getResource("/" + path)).file().getAbsolutePath();
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultSchema": "DB",
  "schemas": [ {
    "type": "jdbc",
    "name": "DB1",
    "jdbcUser": "root",
    "jdbcPassword": "admin",
    "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ignite",
    "jdbcSchema": "ignite"
  }, {
    "type": "jdbc",
    "name": "DB2",
    "jdbcUser": "SYSTEM",
    "jdbcPassword": "SYSTEM",
    "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",
    "jdbcSchema": "SYSTEM"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code if you'd like help debugging it.

Comment: Please find the code details in the question section.